# retrieve image/files such as video using jsp

Tags: jsp

I want to retrieve and display image/files from my table called contacts( which includes the columns "FIRST_NAME","LAST_NAME", and "PHOTO") and display the information on html form for all records in my table.
Is it the same for all other files such as .PDF and .MP4 (or any other files.) If it is some what different please help me. I'm student @ Jimma University (Ethiopia) and I'm currently working my graduation project (web based project) using JSP. I'm new to this programming language and I need full help of you!

and I'm currently using NetBeans 7.3

```
                           Thank you!
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the image in the html page rather than show the name of the image file then probably you will need to write a custom servlet to extract the image from the db and stream it to the browser. So the html code will be like follows.

```
<img src="/imageServlet/123" />
```

You will need to map the servlet you wrote to the path 'imageServlet'. 123 is supposed to be the primary key of the record in the db details of which you are showing. Then inside the servelt you will need to read the image and write it's contents to the output stream of the servlet.